# What is the path of logging.java?

Tags: java

When I try and search in Windows it just gives me "java" or "java/util"  I can't find that in explorer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java.util is probably the package on the classpath for Logger.java

You won't find it in Windows explorer, it'll be inside a jar (rt.jar in the JRE?)

Comment: Logger.java won't be in rt.jar, Logging.class will be.  If you want the source file, you'll need to download the source or view it online.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the Logging class in java.util.logging.logger

The Logger class forwards all logging to whatever Handlers have been attached to it.  You can attach a Handler using the Logger.addHandler(Handler handler) function.

A good handler to use for writing your logs out to file is StreamHandler.

```
File file = new File("path/to/file");
FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
StreamHandler streamHandler = new StreamHandler();
streamHandler.setOutputStream(fileStream);
Logger logger = new Logger();
logger.addHandler(streamHandler);
```

Now, anything logged to logger should go to the filename specified.

See the documentation for [Logger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#addHandler(java.util.logging.Handler)), [StreamHandler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/StreamHandler.html), [FileOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), and [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html).